# Ignore a database when running a loop that compares two databases

Tags: sql-server, database, compare

I'm writing a MS SQL query that takes one database and compares it to many other databases, using a loop. I want to ignore the comparison of when it gets to comparing itself. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What kind of databases MySQL, MS SQL etc? Are you writing an application to do this or using an off the shelf tool?

Comment: @BradFaircloth MS SQL. I'm writing a query that pulls databases and then compares them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would help?

[Database Comparison Tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/205011/SQL-Server-Database-Comparison-Tool)